# Creating plot in ggplot2 from manipulated data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was hoping someone could help me out here. I'm working on a college project and have manipulated a dataset to give me the figures I want, but I'm struggling to figure out how to turn this into a readable barplot with ggplot2.

The dataset I'm using is widely available here: https://www.kaggle.com/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings

I have managed to manipulate the data in order to determine the European sales numbers of certain video games genres below using the following code:

```
vg_action <- (videogames %>% filter(Genre == "Action"))
vg_action_s <- sum(vg_action$EU_Sales)

vg_sports <- (videogames %>% filter(Genre == "Sports"))
vg_sports_s <- sum(vg_sports$EU_Sales)

vg_shooter <- (videogames %>% filter(Genre == "Shooter"))
vg_shooter_s <- sum(vg_shooter$EU_Sales)

vg_rpg <- (videogames %>% filter(Genre == "Role-Playing"))
vg_rpg_s <- sum(vg_rpg$EU_Sales)

vg_racing <- (videogames %>% filter(Genre == "Racing"))
vg_racing_s <- sum(vg_racing$EU_Sales)
```

Each returns a number corresponding to the sales for that genre (eg, `vg_action_s` returns 284.39, `vg_sports_s` returns 184.41 etc). `videogames` is the read in .csv file.

How would I best go about turning this into a barplot using ggplot2, where the x-axis is the genre names (Action, Sports, Racing etc), and the y axis is the value?

I'm very new to R (and coding in general) so I hope I'm explaining myself correctly. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you don't need to make `sum`s of each `Genre` one by one.

One thing weird is sum of `Action` or etc is not like you said. (Although use same code with yours)

If there's any problem, please let me know.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

videogames %>%
  group_by(Genre) %>%
  summarise(m = sum(EU_Sales)) %>%
  filter(Genre %in% c("Action", "Sports", "Shooter", "Role-Playing", "Racing")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Genre, y = m, fill = Genre)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Or just using your vg...things can be done like

```
df <- data.frame(sums = c(vg_action_s, vg_sports_s, vg_shooter_s, vg_rpg_s, vg_racing_s),
                 Genre = c("Action", "Sports", "Shooter", "Role-Playing", "Racing"))
ggplot(df, aes(x = Genre, y = sums, fill = Genre)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! I actually manipulated the data slightly differently in practice, but kept it as simple as possible here when I was explaining it, hence why you had a different result. This is exactly what I was looking for though, you've saved me a lot of hassle. Cheers!